# dataSnapshop.getValue(MyClass.class) closes my app - I can't read from Firebase database

Tags: android, database, firebase

I am making an android app linked to Firebase. I am new to both Firebase and Android app development. Adding data from the very same class in the database works well, but reading that data closes my app.

Below is my logcat: 
    07-29 20:20:19.376 23784 23784 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    07-29 20:20:19.378 23784 23784 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-29 20:20:19.378 23784 23784 E AndroidRuntime: Process:, PID: 23784
    07-29 20:20:19.378 23784 23784 E AndroidRuntime: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class is missing a constructor with no arguments
Below is my code:

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

    ....
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new, container, false);
.....

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference simpleClassDatabaseReference = database.getReference().child("SimpleClass");
......    
            ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    SimpleClass simpleClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(SimpleClass.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };simpleClassDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

This is my simple class:

```
public class SimpleClass {
    String simpleWord;
    String secondWord;

    public SimpleClass (String simpleWord, String secondWord){
        this.simpleWord = simpleWord;
        this.secondWord = secondWord;
    }

    public String getSimpleWord() {
        return simpleWord;
    }

    public String getSecondWord() {
        return secondWord;
    }
}
```

and this is how i write that class in Firebase:

```
SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass("HI!!", "Hi again!!");
DatabaseReference mSimpleClassDatabaseReference = database.getReference().child("SimpleClass");
mSimpleClassDatabaseReference.push().setValue(simpleClass);
```

Comment: Simple class needs a no arguments construtor, you need to create a construtor like that: public SimpleClass (){
            
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to fix try do that:

```
public class SimpleClass {
    String simpleWord;
    String secondWord;

    public SimpleClass (){
        //construtor with no arguments
    }

    public SimpleClass (String simpleWord, String secondWord){
    this.simpleWord = simpleWord;
    this.secondWord = secondWord;
}

    public String getSimpleWord() {
        return simpleWord;
    }

    public String getSecondWord() {
        return secondWord;
    }
}
```

Your error is Simple class nedds a construtor with no arguments.